# String Concatenation using '+' operator

Tags: c#, .net, string

Looking at the `string` class metadata, I only see the operators `==` and `!=` overloaded. So how is it able to  perform concatenation for the '`+`' operator?

**Edit**:

Some interesting notes from Eric Lippert on string concatenation:

[Part 1](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/)

[Part 2](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/24/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-two/)

There is also a super article from Joel referred in part 2 (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

It doesn't - the C# compiler does :)

So this code:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = "there";
string z = "chaps";
string all = x + y + z;
```

actually gets compiled as:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = "there";
string z = "chaps";
string all = string.Concat(x, y, z);
```

(Gah - intervening edit removed other bits accidentally.)

The benefit of the C# compiler noticing that there are multiple string concatenations here is that you don't end up creating an intermediate string of `x + y` which then needs to be copied again as part of the concatenation of `(x + y)` and `z`. Instead, we get it all done in one go.

EDIT: Note that the compiler *can't* do anything if you concatenate in a loop. For example, this code:

```
string x = "";
foreach (string y in strings)
{
    x += y;
}
```

just ends up as equivalent to:

```
string x = "";
foreach (string y in strings)
{
    x = string.Concat(x, y);
}
```

... so this *does* generate a lot of garbage, and it's why you should use a `StringBuilder` for such cases. I have an [article going into more details about the two](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html) which will hopefully answer further questions.

Comment: Good answer; just a follow-up question: if you're concatenating strings inside a loop, how does the compiler work the .Concat operator when it can't know in advance what's going to be in the loop.

Comment: Ah ok! And that's why it's better to use the StringBuilder for concatenations?

Comment: @frenchie: That's why it's better to use StringBuilder for *repeated* concatenation... but why it's not worth it for concatenation *of a fixed number of values*.

Comment: @Jon-Skeet: thanks for the quick clarification...i should have checked in IL as well..and this is how int adds as well? by calling the Add method?

Comment: StringBuilder is the way to go for string concatenation. + operator would copy the entire string to another new variable and cause and overload

Comment: @Enggr: When looping, yes. *Not* when concatenating multiple expressions in a single statement though, as per my first example. Note that using `StringBuilder` still requires the whole string to be copied.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: No, `int` uses built-in IL instructions. But `decimal` would use the `op_Add` operator implementation, for example.

Comment: But note that nowadays the `string.Concat` and `string.Join` methods have many overloads, including some taking in an `IEnumerable<>` instance. So they are more convenient to use in most cases than to use a `StringBuilder` (I don't know if these methods use a `StringBuilder` internally, I just say that they are more convenient in most cases).