# Add into string field

Tags: c#, string, format, tostring, stringbuilder

tell me pls what's problem with this code C#.

```
        string str = string.Empty;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            str += i.ToString();
```

This was interview question.

Comment: No problems. It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: This may lead to Memory consumption problem, here + operator creates 1000 strings, use `StringBuilder` in such cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually there is no problem with your code.

inthis case [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is more appropriate than `string`.

because `StringBuilder` is mutable whereas `string` is `immutable`.

so whenever you modify the String object using `+=` it creates a new `string` object so at the end of your loop it creates many string objects.

but if you use `StringBuilder`:  same object will be modified each time you Append the `Strings` to it.

You can find more info from MSDN: [StringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The String object is immutable. Every time you use one of the methods
>   in the System.String class, you create a new string object in memory,
>   which requires a new allocation of space for that new object. In
>   situations where you need to perform repeated modifications to a
>   string, the overhead associated with creating a new String object can
>   be costly. The System.Text.StringBuilder class can be used when you
>   want to modify a string without creating a new object. For example,
>   using the StringBuilder class can boost performance when concatenating
>   many strings together in a loop.

**Solution :**

This

```
    string str = string.Empty;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        str += i.ToString();
```

Shouldbe this

```
    StringBuilder str =new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        str.Append(i.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator).

`the compiler can't do anything if you concatenate in a loop and this does generate a lot of garbage.`