# Proper way in C# to combine an arbitrary number of strings into a single string

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, data-structures

I breezed through the documentation for the `string` class and didn't see any good tools for combining an arbitrary number of strings into a single string. The best procedure I could come up with in my program is

```
string [] assetUrlPieces = { Server.MapPath("~/assets/"), 
                             "organizationName/",
                             "categoryName/",
                             (Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "/"),
                             (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName) + "/")
                           };

string assetUrl = combinedString(assetUrlPieces);
```

---

```
private string combinedString ( string [] pieces )
{
    string alltogether = "";
    foreach (string thispiece in pieces) alltogether += alltogether + thispiece;
    return alltogether; 
}
```

but that seems like too much code and too much inefficiency (from the string addition) and awkwardness.

Comment: Check out [`string.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 17):

If you want to insert a separator between values, [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join) is your friend. If you *just* want to concatenate the strings, then you can use [`string.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Concat):

```
string assetUrl = string.Concat(assetUrlPieces);
```

That's marginally simpler (and *possibly* more efficient, but probably insignificantly) than calling `string.Join` with an empty separator.

As noted in comments, if you're *actually* building up the array at the same point in the code that you do the concatenation, and you don't need the array for anything else, just use concatenation directly:

```
string assetUrl = Server.MapPath("~/assets/") +
    "organizationName/" + 
    "categoryName/" +
    Guid.NewGuid() + "/" +
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName) + "/";
```

... or potentially use `string.Format` instead.

Comment: Some  Jon Skeet suggested to just use plus instead of building array and iterating over it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator as it is compiled into `String.Concat` anyway...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: True, but I'm assuming that in the OP's *real* situation, the array is coming from elsewhere...

Answer (score 15):

I prefer using `string.Join`:

```
var result = string.Join("", pieces);
```

You can read about `string.Join` [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is the fastest and easiest way to do it. Nitpick: Use `string.Empty` maybe.

Comment: Side note: this (along with `StringBuilder` and `String.Concat` for small number of strings) is right way to combine multiple strings when they are just text. For url/path cases it is preferable to use `Uri`, `UriBuilder`, `Path` types...

Comment: @JonSkeet Learning everyday :)

Answer (score 4):

You want a `StringBuilder`, I think.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(pieces.Count());
foreach(var s in pieces) {
    sb.Append(s);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

**Update**

@FiredFromAmazon.com:  I think you'll want to go with the `string.Concat` solution offered by others for

1. Its sheer simplicity
2. Higher performance.  Under the hood, it uses `FillStringChecked`, which does pointer copies, whereas `string.Join` uses `StringBuilder`. See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1512.  (Thank you to @Bas).

Comment: This is almost how `string.Join` is implemented, however it is optimized if it knows the number of strings beforehand to calculate the length of the buffer, http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,06d13c9cb8b83f5d. No use in reimplementing it.

Comment: @Bas: thanks, updated construction of StringBuilder with the count of Strings in the pieces array to show use of length of buffer as per your remark.

Comment: @FiredFromAmazon.com see my update above about using string.Concat

Answer (score 3):

`string.Concat` is the most appropriate method for what you want.

```
var result = string.Concat(pieces);
```

Unless you want to put delimiters between the individual strings.  Then you'd use `string.Join`

```
var result = string.Join(",", pieces); // comma delimited result.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this with a regular for loop: 
(since you can use the indices, plus I like these loops better than foreach loops)

```
   private string combinedString(string[] pieces)
   {
    string alltogether = "";
    for (int index = 0; index <= pieces.Length - 1; index++) {
        if (index != pieces.Length - 1) {
             alltogether += string.Format("{0}/" pieces[index]);
        }
    }
    return alltogether;
```