# Task.Run() how to pass object owned by other thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, async-await, task-parallel-library

How can i pass for example the text of a textBox UI element into a Task.Run() method? This code will throw an exception(... other thread owns it). When i pass the filter variabele, the exception is gone, is this because the string gets passed as value?

```
private async void filterTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentSession.SessionFilenames != null)
    {
        string filter = filterTextBox.Text;
        dirListing.ItemsSource = await Task<IEnumerable<string>>.Run(()=> Filterfiles(filterTextBox.Text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats the case

Comment: basically, yes :-) read more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120785/1132334). But the opposite is not true: it fails with the textbox because the textbox is a [control on the UI thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls), not because its passed by ref vs. by val.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use objects with thread affinity (such as the `TextBox` object) in a thread other than the one that owns that object.

But most objects *don't* have thread affinity. They are not owned by any particular thread and can be used anywhere. That includes the `string` object returned by `filterTextBox.Text`, which you store in the `filter` local variable.

So, just use that value instead:

```
dirListing.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(()=> Filterfiles(filter));
```

Note that you should not need to specify the type parameter for the `Task.Run()` method call either. The compiler will infer the type based on the expression used in the call.