# How "object.ToString()" evaluate in string concatenate statement?

Tags: c#, tostring

My question is how "object.ToString()" method evaluate in string concatenate statement?.

I mean if write code like-:

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name{get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Employee Name {0}", Name);
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Employee emp = new Employee() {Name = "Ni3"};
    string result = "Result = " + emp;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

it yields -

```
Result = Employee Name Ni3
```

so compiler transforms the statement like this -:

```
string result= String.Concat("Result = ",emp.ToString());
```

or there is another reason.

Comment: Seems that you are interested in [the `+` operator for strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator)?

Comment: Yes and thanks to @Hans for quickly resolve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite, you are using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx) that uses two object parameters.

And *this* method calls `.ToString()` on those objects, after a null-check. See the remarks section:

> The method concatenates arg0 and arg1by calling the parameterless
>   ToString method of arg0 and arg1; it does not add any delimiters.
>   String.Empty is used in place of any null argument.
>   If either of the
>   arguments is an array reference, the method concatenates a string
>   representing that array, instead of its members (for example,
>   "System.String[]").