# Why concatenating two null string results an empty string?

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I just saw a weird result while I tried to concatenate two `null` strings: it returns an empty one! I can not imagine if it have some utility or why this occurs.

Example:

```
string sns = null;
sns = sns + sns;
// It results in a String.Empty

string snss = null;
snss = String.Concat(snss, snss);
// It results in a String.Empty too!
```

Can someone tell me why it returns a `String.Empty` instead of `null`?

Comment: The `+` operator is a shorthand for the [`String.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx) method. If the arguments passed were `null` then it turns them into an empty string.

Comment: I have been programming in C#, C++, and C for many years and only just now discovered this today!  In my head I was thinking string-concatenation would always yield null if all arguments were null.  How have I never noticed this behavior before?  I feel like such a newb now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fragment from C# Language Specification, the “7.8.4 Addition operator” section:

> String concatenation:
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
> string operator +(string x, object y);
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> These overloads of the binary `+` operator perform string concatenation. If an operand of string concatenation is `null`, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual `ToString` method inherited from type `object`. If `ToString` returns `null`, an empty string is substituted.

Comment: Good find, I could find it D=.

Comment: See more at [Google Books](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=s-IH_x6ytuQC&lpg=PT432&ots=lsc19Y7M6V&dq=%E2%80%9C7.8.4%20Addition%20operator%E2%80%9D&hl=pt-BR&pg=PT433#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9C7.8.4%20Addition%20operator%E2%80%9D&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

If the string is null, it returns String.Empty.

As for the operator +, I am not too sure.

Comment: For the downvote, look at ln 3002. =)

Comment: `+` just uses the `Concat` method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator

Comment: @paqogomez nice thank you, ill check out that SO question.

Comment: Thank you for clarify. Unfortunately I only can chose one answer, but I upvoted both. Living and learning!