# String concatenation : += operator versus string array joined

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

The concatenation in many language using the `+=` operator create a new string instance. It is preffered to use a `string[]` that we join at the end.

In Javascript :

```
var myString = new Array("Hello");
myString.push(" ");
myString.push("world !");
console.log(myString.join(''));
```

is more efficient that :

```
var myString = "Hello";
myString += " ";
myString += "world !";
console.log(myString);
```

In C#, does the `+=` operator create a new string ?
Is the StringBuilder more efficient that using a `string[]` ?

Comment: This is the kind of question that is best answered with real-world examples and benchmarks rather than pure theoretical examination. Can you provide examples that you would like to see benchmarked?

Comment: See http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1532499/579895)

Comment: Note that `a += b` or `a = a + b` gets translated to `a = string.Concat(a, b)` by the C# compiler

Comment: What is more, you would never use `string[]` in C# for this, as arrays in C# have constant length and changing it requires allocation of new memory and copying the contents. You might try to use `List<string>`, but `StringBuilder` or `String.Concat` is the way to go, depending on the case.

Comment: Another tangentially relevant SO post:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator

Comment: They serve two different purposes.  `StringBuilder` is used to directly concatenate an arbitrary number of strings, whether in a collection or not - `string.Join` is used to concatenate strings (from a collection) with a separator.  If you want to use `Join` to concatenate strings with an empty separator there's nothing stopping you, but it's not the _intended_ purpose.

Comment: the question is do you want to compare string.join or string[].join?

Comment: @DStanley If you don't have a separator, then you should be using `Concat`.  It's a method specifically to concatenate an arbitrary number of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In C#, does the += operator create a new string ?**

`String` is immutable in C# and Java. That means you can not modify it. Every method that modifys a string (`+=` executes a method too) returns a new instance of a `string`.

**Is the `StringBuilder` more efficient that using `.Join()` on a `string[]` ?**

`StringBuilder` is more performant (that are some nanosecs per call) than using `.Join` on an `string[]`.
So it does make "sence" when you do that really often in a loop or something.

Comment: The second question is using `StringBuilder` versus calling `Join` on a string array.

Comment: Thanks for that explaination. Editing my answer

Comment: "StringBuilder is more performant (that are some nanosecs per call) than using .Join on an string[]" how do you know this?

Comment: [String.Join vs. StringBuilder: which is faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/585897/43846)

Comment: @stuartd The question is joining multiple string[]. Not using string.Join. At least i think so

Comment: @DStanley benchmarked it. In every attempt the Join-variant was about 3.5 times faster.