# Show many values in DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

hello how can i show a Name and LastName in DropDonwListFor, Because in my example i show Name without LastName

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(@model => @model.Conseiller, new SelectList(ViewBag.User, "Id","Name", "LastName"), new { @class = "form-controml"})
```

Comment: You need to build and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in your controller (where the value of the `Text` property is the concatenated values of `Name` and `LastName`

Comment: You have to combine Name and Lastname at the time of query and pass it with a viewmodel to view

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two columns and then use FullName variable as `SelectList` display

```
string FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", User.Name, User.LastName);
```

Comment: Don't use `+` for string concatenation. Using `string.Format("{0} {1}", User.Name, User.LastName)` is more efficent

Comment: Performance. strings are immutable so each time you do `+` you create a new instance. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator