# What should replace comparisons with False in python?

Tags: python, boolean, pychecker

I have a function that returns `False` if something isn't found, and returns a data structure with what I'm looking for otherwise.  When I assign the value returned from this function to a variable `my_var` in a `for` loop, I do a `if my_var == False: continue` to carry on.

`pychecker` doesn't like this and reports `Comparisons with False are not necessary and may not work as expected`.

What's the python way for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a return value indicating absence of a result, `None` is almost always better.

- If you must use `False`, use `not my_var`. This assumes non - `False` return values are never "falsy" (`bool()` converts it into `False` - this is the case for empty strings, empty collections, and a few other things).
- If objects may be falsy but must be distinguished from `False`, then the comparison is necessary and you'll have to ignore the error (a minor variation, `my_var is False` would be slightly more idiomatic, but it's virtually the same). But that's not a nice situation to be in and you should avoid it for the fake of clarity.

To repeat myself: If at all possible, use `None` and test for `my_var is None`.

Comment: Just the under-the-hood explanation I needed.  Thanks, @delnan!

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would return `None` instead of `False` i.e. if an object doesn't match. And then check `if my_var == None:` as all `not 0`, `not False` and `not None` return `True`.

Comment: It is wrong to use comparison operators with `None`. `is` or `is not` must be used

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check for a falsy value:

```
myval = findit('something')
if not myval:
   "not found"
```

You don't want to do this if you could actually return a value for the "is-found" case which has a falsy value. E.g., if `[]` (empty list) is found, this will still report "not found".

If you care that it is actually `False`, use `is`. `True`, `False`, and `None` are singletons, so the identity comparison operator is used.

```
if myval is False:
   "not found"
```

In this case you are using `False` as a sentinel value to indicate that there is no result.

Usually `None` is used as a sentinel "no-value", however, so I suggest you change the signature of your function to return `None` if no value is found. This conforms better with Python idiom and the behavior of methods such as `{}.get('missing-key')`.

```
myval = findit('something')
if myval is None:
    "not found"
```

In cases where no sentinel value is possible because any value could be returned (even `None` or `False`), Python uses an exception to signal that no value was found. E.g. `{}['missing-key']` will raise `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd just use `not`:

```
if not my_var: continue
```

Comment: If the datastructure returned might be falsy, this may match too much.

Comment: @FrancisAvila If that's the case then one could test if the value in `my_var` has type `bool` -- however, one would hope that objects and bools aren't being mixed in the data structure...

Comment: What I mean is `(not []) == True`. If his function could return an empty list or string or 0 (or any object which has a magic method giving it a false value), then this will surprise him.

Comment: @FrancisAvila Right, I know what you're saying.  I'm saying that having lists and bools on the same level of a structure is not a good idea.  :)

Comment: That's exactly what the OP's function is doing. Datastructure (e.g. `[]`) if "found", `False` if "not found". He's using False as a sentinel value.

Answer (score 1):

Python is actually more strongly typed than C++ in this regard. Only genuine booleans can be True or False.

So `my_var` must be a boolean. Therefore you just check it as one.

```
if not my_var:
     continue
```

Comment: Since the variable could equally be a data structure, I think I'm not respecting the idea of a genuine boolean.  The data structure would return True if evaluated, but what you're saying is that it's kind of an abuse of polymorph power, yes?

Comment: By "strongly typed", do you mean "less inclined to do implicit conversions"? Then please say that instead of the [ill-defined-to-the-point-of-meaninglessness word](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929697/395760) that is "{strongly, weakly} typed".

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Python uses dynamic typing but avoids implicit conversions.