# Update or replace value in df when conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of city names and a df with city, state, and zipcode columns. Some of the zipcodes are missing. When a zipcode is missing, I want to use a generic zipcode based on the city. For example, the city is San Jose so the zipcode should be a generic 'SJ_zipcode'.

```
pattern_city = '|'.join(cities) #works

foundit = ( (df['cty_nm'].str.contains(pattern_city, flags=re.IGNORECASE)) & (df['zip_cd']==0) & (df['st_cd'].str.match('CA') ) ) #works--is this foundit a df?

df['zip_cd'] = foundit.replace( 'SJ_zipcode' ) #nope, error
```

Error: "Invalid dtype for pad_1d [bool]"

Implemented with `where`

```
df['zip_cd'].where( (df['cty_nm'].str.contains(pattern_city, flags=re.IGNORECASE)) & (df['zip_cd']==0) & (df['st_cd'].str.match('CA') ), "SJ_Zipcode", inplace = True) #nope, empty set; all set to nan?
```

Implemented with `loc`

```
df['zip_cd'].loc[ (df['cty_nm'].str.contains(pattern_city, flags=re.IGNORECASE)) & (df['zip_cd']==0) & (df['st_cd'].str.match('CA') ) ] = "SJ_Zipcode"
```

Some possible solutions that did not work

- `df.loc[df['First Season'] > 1990, 'First Season'] = 1`  which I used as `df.loc[foundit, 'zip_cd'] = 'SJ_zipcode'` [Pandas DataFrame: replace all values in a column, based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition) and similar/same as [Conditional Replace Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas/44311454)
- `df['c'] = df.apply( lambda row: row['a']*row['b'] if np.isnan(row['c']) else row['c'], axis=1)` however, I am not multiplying values https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17769/how-to-fill-missing-value-based-on-other-columns-in-pandas-dataframe
- I tried a solution using `where`, however, it seemed to replace the values where the condition was not met with nan--but the nan value was not helpful https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html
- This conditional approach looked promising but then without looping with each value I was confused by how does anything happen... [What should replace comparisons with False in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229215/what-should-replace-comparisons-with-false-in-python)
- An example using `replace` which does not have the multiple conditions and pattern [Replacing few values in a pandas dataframe column with another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060098/replacing-few-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-another-value)

An additional 'want'; I want to update a dataframe with values, I do not want to create a new dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    city         state        zip
0   Burbank      California   44325
1   Anaheim      California   nan
2   El Cerrito   California   57643
3   Los Angeles  California   56734
4   san Fancisco California   32819

def generate_placeholder_zip(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['zip'] ):
        row['zip'] =row['city']+'_ZIPCODE'
    return row   

df.apply(generate_placeholder_zip, axis =1)

    city          state         zip
0   Burbank       California    44325
1   Anaheim       California    Anaheim_ZIPCODE
2   El Cerrito    California    57643
3   Los Angeles   California    56734
4   san Fancisco  California    32819
```